# Scala type mismatch: default.type (with underlying type A1 => B1)

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I'm trying to write a function which will handle exception in future and returns new future, but I'm running into trouble and can't make sense of error message

```
scala> def composeHandlingFuture[T](fut: Future[T], default: T): Future[T] =
     | fut recover { case e: Exception => default }
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : default.type (with underlying type A1 => B1)
 required: T
       fut recover { case e: Exception => default }
                                          ^
```

Isn't `default.type` equal to `T` as signature requires? How does it have anything to do with `type A1 => B1`?

Any help appreciated.

P.S. I'm using Scala 2.10.1

Comment: I can't explain the error message, but removing the explicit return type lets you define the function without it complaining

Comment: Yes, but the return type becomes scala.concurrent.Future[Any], which is not what I want

Comment: Ah yes, just noticed that too. IntelliJ lies and says the return type is `Future[T]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from typer phase. If we use -Xprint:typer then we can see the problem:

```
def composeHandlingFuture[T >: Nothing <: Any](fut: scala.concurrent.Future[T], default: T): scala.concurrent.Future[T] = fut.recover[T](({
      @SerialVersionUID(0) final <synthetic> class $anonfun extends scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction[Throwable,T] with Serializable {
        /////// Init method //////

        final override def applyOrElse[A1 >: Nothing <: Throwable, B1 >: T <: Any](x1: A1, default: A1 => B1): B1 = ((x1.asInstanceOf[Throwable]: Throwable): Throwable @unchecked) match {
          case (e @ (_: Exception)) => <error: value default> // your argument comes here, but name clash happens
          case (defaultCase$ @ _) => default.apply(x1)
        };


        //// IsDefinedAt method ////
  }
```

The problem is in PartialFunction, second argument to aplyOrElse is also called `default` with type `A1 => B1`. [Here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala#L2641) is it in the Scala compiler Typer phase, so you can make a ticket i guess

Answer (score 0):

Strange, as soon as I renamed `default` variable, everything compiled fine:

```
scala> def composeHandlingFuture[T](fut: Future[T], x: T): Future[T] =
     | fut recover { case e: Exception => x }
composeHandlingFuture: [T](fut: scala.concurrent.Future[T], x: T)scala.concurrent.Future[T]
```